# How can I print with formatting when debugging a Rust program with GDB?

Tags: formatting, gdb, rust

When I try to print with string formatting, like I do when debugging in C, I get an error of conversion:

```
(gdb) printf "%s\n", "hello world"
Value can't be converted to integer.
```

Expected:

```
(gdb) printf "%s\n", "hello world"
$2 = "hello world"
```

Diagnostic info:

```
$ rust-gdb -v
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.12.1
.....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `printf`, it expects the expression to be either a number or a
pointer.  Pulled from [Commands for Controlled Output](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Output.html)

> printf template, expressions…
>
> The expressions are separated by commas and may be either numbers or pointers

If I had checked the type of `"hello world"` with gdb's `ptype` command, I would have noticed that it's an object and not a number or a pointer.

```
(gdb) ptype "hello world"
type = struct &str {
  data_ptr: u8 *,
  length: usize,
}
```

To resolve this, change the argument to the string's property called `data_ptr`.

```
(gdb) ptype "hello world".data_ptr
type = u8 *

(gdb) p "hello world".data_ptr
$14 = (u8 *) 0x101100080 "hello world\000"
```

Returning `data_ptr` should work because it's a pointer (`u8 *`) and it points to an address that is the start of the string.

```
(gdb) printf "%s\n", "hello world".data_ptr
hello world
```

---

**Be aware** not to mix up with `print` as this **wouldn't work**.

```
(gdb) print "%s\n", "hello world".data_ptr
Could not convert character to `UTF-8' character set
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the `data_ptr` is NUL-terminated, so it seems like this is likely to fail at the worst time.